# Pad 0's between 2 columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to pad 0's between 2 columns.

Example: I have storeid 123 and id 4, I need the result as 1230000000000004.

Total 15 characters should be there also the length of storeid and id may vary.

Please suggest how to code.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a coding service website. Show us, what you have done so far in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Comment: see `concat()` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is This What You need to do ? Try this Once will help you someway

**Sample Data**

```
SELECT * INTO #SampleTable From
(
SELECT '123' as COLUMN1 , '4' AS COLUMN2
UNION ALL 
SELECT '34' , '567'
UNION ALL
SELECT '891011' , '121314'
) AS A
```

**Query**

```
SELECT COLUMN1,COLUMN2,
COLUMN1 + REPLICATE ('0',15-(LEN(COLUMN1)+LEN(COLUMN2))) +COLUMN2 AS YourOuputColumn
FROM #SampleTable

*** Result ***

COLUMN1 COLUMN2   YourOuputColumn
123     4         123000000000004
34      567       340000000000567
891011  121314    891011000121314
```